# How to avoid password prompt when starting Synaptic?

Tags: debian, sudo, password, root, synaptic

Whenever I start the Synaptic package manager, it asks for a password. How do I make it skip that dialog?

I'm using Debian 9.8.

Comment: [It will not be a problem for Debian 10.](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2019/04/msg00103.html)  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Why? What are people supposed to use for package management? Only terminal?

Comment: Also, this is technically not Synaptic specific, but that's the only program where I remember encountering that, so people will likely search for that.

Comment: Where is the problem ? You don't start Synaptic package manager all 5 minutes !

Comment: @ctac_ You could for example have a really long password and don't want to enter it once on login and another time when starting Synaptic, mounting something or whatever. And even if that doesn't count for you, there's the simple argument that I am the owner of my computer and it should do what I say without asking for information it already has over and over.

Comment: Ok, so always work with root, This way, you never need a password. For mounting something, , It's another way and @FabianRöling answer don't resolve that. I think it is another operating system wich allow that. I can't remember his name . Ah yes start with windows and you can make what you want without password.

Comment: How do I always work with root? You mean after every program I install, I should always edit the menu entry, for every keyboard combination that opens something, I should rebind it to use root, for every other thing that could possibly open something, I should change it to execute as root? That's an intriguing idea, even though I think it would be a looot of effort to do consistently, but sadly it won't work. Chrome for example simply does not run as root and some other programs also work differently. Some system settings are also user specific and wouldn't work correctly if set as root. Etc.…

Answer (score 2):

I originally thought that editing `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic.policy` would do it (see the old versions of this answer if you want to see that method), but I was told that that would get reset whenever Synaptic gets updated. You would also need to do it for every single program.

A better solution was given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/730949): Create the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-nopassword.pkla` (or any other file name, just the location and ending has to be the same) and fill it with:

```
[No password prompt]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=*
ResultActive=yes
```

I tried it in a Debian VM and it successfully skipped the prompt for Synaptic.

Comment: No, that's not the way to do this. Any edits to files in `/usr/share` will be lost when the package owning that file gets updated. The right way to set Polkit privileges is to create PKLA files in `/etc/polkit-1`, allowing your user the `com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic.policy` action with `allow_active`, etc. set to yes. You don't need to, and shouldn't, edit these XML files instead. See, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/158442

Comment: @muru You're right, that works and it's much quicker! (And yes, I did try it on a different system.) What do you suggest for this question? Should I delete the answer and flag the question as duplicate of that other question? Should I edit this question completely to change it to the other solution? Should I delete both?

Comment: My example is from Ask Ubuntu, so this question can't be closed as a duplicate. You can edit this *answer* to correct it, however.

Comment: As mentioned in a response to [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/123260/1085131). You can use `Identity=unix-user:scott` to only allow the user `scott` to do the action.