# Why graphic installers ask for password even when I have NOPASSWD in sudoers?

Tags: linux, sudo, gui

This seems a "feature" as it is consistent on all distributions I tried.

On my home development machine I routinely install new software and do other tweaks, typing my password several times/day is not fun so I add a

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

line to `/etc/sudoers.d/user`.

This works as expected from the command line (i.e.: `sudo apt install whatever` will *not* ask for a password), but it seems to be completely ignored from graphical programs (i.e.: `update-manager`, `synaptic`, `packagekit` and similar tools *will* ask for a password).

What is the rationale behind this? (or: "what am I doing wrong"?)

Update: a quick perusal of `polkit` documentation left me a bit baffled: is there a simple way to achieve the same result (Insist for a confirmation, like the need to prepend `sudo` which is important to draw your attention on potentially dangerous actions, but reduce typing exercise)?

Comment: As for the update: https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not using `sudo`. They're using [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit). Polkit configuration is independent of `sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks. Could You explain *why* polkit chose not to honor sudoers? ... and, possibly, could You explain *how* to convince polkit to stop bothering me? (that was the OP question, not *how* they manage to defeat me)TiA

Comment: @ZioByte there's no reason for it to. They work on different principles (`sudo` works on controlling access to commands, graphical applications using `polkit` aren't running commands). And your OP question isn't asking how to, but only (and explicitly) why your attempt doesn't work. The how is already answered elsewhere, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510927/, https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/158442

Comment: @ZioByte if you want to know how to avoid that, please edit your question since it is currently asking why this happens and what the rationale behind it is, not how to avoid it.

Comment: @terdon: I'll accept this answer. I am a bit pissed off because it seems "root cause" is: someone started using a new marvelous system (`polkit`) and doesn't give  damn if it works well with legacy software (`sudo`). I understand in OpenSource everyone is free to do whatever he sees fit, but distributions using two completely different systems to achieve the same result *at the same time* (this is not "alternative") is not nice (to be polite).

Comment: It's... considerably more complicated than that, there are very good reasons why `sudo` should not be used by GUI programs. See, for example, [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006).  I think you probably should ask a new question about this, it really is much more reasonable than you are assuming (although I do understand why you would assume so).

Comment: @terdon: I understand quite well what's in the linked thread and, IMHO of course, does *not* apply. I do not want to run `sudo update-manager` (or something similar) which would incur in the cited problems, I cannot grasp why a graphical program needing to escalate privileges (it knows, because it's asking pass!) could not use `sudo` or have `polkit` try to parse `sudoers` (or, better yet, use `sudo` under the hood as a last resort if no specific policy is defined)

Comment: @ZioByte  as I said, `sudo` is fundamentally based on a command-based system. GUIs don't typically use commands, nor should they have to. They use libraries to execute actions. Polkit is based on actions.